# poodle attack/padding oracle attack

Tags: encryption, openssl

According to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POODLE) or https://www.us-cert.gov/ncas/alerts/TA14-290A

this is an issue with the SSL v3.0 non deterministic padding used in CBC. 
Is AES in CBC mode itself is un-secure or it is an issue only when used in SSLv3.0/TLS ? Can you please clarify ?

I use openssl (an old version before the poodle attack fix) aes-128-cbc mode to encrypt a file like below, openssl enc -aes-128-cbc -in test -out test.enc -K $key128 -iv $iv

Is test.enc secure as far as the poodle attack/padding oracle attack is concerned ? If not secure, how can I make it secure ? will patching openssl to the new version take care ?

Thanks

Comment: The problem can be with (mostly) unchecked padding plus an oracle, in *any* cipher and mode that uses padding. SSL/TLS does not have any modes that pad other than CBC, but it does have ciphers other than AES that operate in CBC with padding. `enc` with a block-mode cipher uses PKCS#5/7 padding which is checked.

Answer (score 1):

POODLE requires a MITM component to be successful. You need to have a long enough stream of cyphertexts before you are able to decypher the stream. Encrypting a single file does not expose MITM vectors.

Comment: MITM is "Man in the Middle", and -component?

Comment: POODLE requires you to be able to be in the stream of communication and to be able to modify that stream.